# html tag having big font-size and display inline (no CSS)

Tags: html, tags

Is there any HTML tag that has big text, similar to `h1`, but that is also inline displaying? I mean that does not go in a new line.

Comment: @divy3993 Default font-size for `h1` is 2em and bold weight.

Answer (score 0):

I guess no other such HTML tag, but you can try this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m5ubq7ju/1/)

```css
h1
{
    border:1px solid red;
}

.text 
{
    line-height:0px;
    height:auto;
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px solid red;    
}
```

```html
<h1>Hey There</h1>
<span class="text">Hey There</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<h1 style="display: inline;">...</h1>` - no new line before;

`<h1 style="white-space: nowrap;">...</h1>` - no break line inside;